# Is it a code smell if I have the need to save a Backbone.Collection?

Tags: javascript, rest, backbone.js

I've been trying to wrap my head around best RESTful practices while using BackboneJS. I feel like I've written myself into a bit of a knot and could use some guidance.

My scenario is this: a user wants to create a new Playlist with N items in it. The data for the N items is coming from a third-party API in bursts of 50 items. As such, I want to add a new, empty Playlist and, as the bursts of 50 come in, save the items and add to my Playlist.

This results in my Playlist model having a method, addItems, which looks like:

```
addItems: function (videos, callback) {
    var itemsToSave = new PlaylistItems();
    var self = this;

    //  Create a new PlaylistItem with each Video.
    videos.each(function (video) {

        var playlistItem = new PlaylistItem({
            playlistId: self.get('id'),
            video: video
        });

        itemsToSave.push(playlistItem);
    });

    itemsToSave.save({}, {
        success: function () {

            //  OOF TERRIBLE.
            self.fetch({
                success: function () {
                    //  TODO: For some reason when I call self.trigger then allPlaylists triggers fine, but if I go through fetch it doesnt trigger?
                    self.trigger('reset', self);

                    if (callback) {
                        callback();
                    }

                }
            });

        },
        error: function (error) {
            console.error("There was an issue saving" + self.get('title'), error);
        }
    });
}
```

ItemsToSave is generally a Collection with 50 items in it. Since BackboneJS does not provide a Save for Collections, I wrote my own. I didn't care much for creating a Model wrapper for my Collection.

So, when I call Save, none of my items have IDs. The database assigns the IDs, but that information isn't implicitly updated by Backbone because I'm saving a Collection and not a Model. As such, once the save is successful, I call fetch on my Playlist to retrieve the updated information. This is terrible because a Playlist could have thousands of items in it -- I don't want to be fetching thousands of items every time I save multiple.

So, I'm thinking maybe I need to override the Collection's parse method and manually map the server's response back to the Collection.

This all seems... overkill/wrong. Am I doing something architecturally incorrect? How does a RESTful architecture handle such a scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is do what works and feels clean enough and disregard what the RESTafarians credence might be. Bulk create, bulk update, bulk delete are real world use cases that the REST folk just close their eyes and pretend don't exist. Something along these lines sounds like a reasonable first attempt to me:

- create a `bulkAdd` method or override `add` carefully if you are feeling confident
- don't make models or add them to the collection yet though
- do your bulk POST or whatever to get them into the database and get the assigned IDs back
- then add them as models to the collection